# Lotus Domino creating database

Tags: lotus-domino

How to create lotus domino database? I have installed domino designer 8.5, lotus admin 8.5 and lotus server. I have configured and launch domino server. So now I need to create database and connect to it with java. Connection is the second part and first I need to find out how to create this db. In tutorials I saw that I need to use domino developer to do that. But there is no such function in domino developer. Can someone tell me, how to do it?

Comment: One thing that might help is that in a lot if menus the word application and database are used synonymously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to create lotus domino database?

**From the Notes client do File - > Application - New**

I have installed domino designer 8.5, lotus admin 8.5 and lotus server.

good, you seem ready

I have configured and launch domino server. So now I need to create database and connect to it with java.

**So you have written some java on the OS level and need to connect to notes using the Notes API? first step is to read about the notes.jar and ncso.jar. 
Did you know that a Notes database is an eclipse project?**

Connection is the second part and first I need to find out how to create this db. 
In tutorials I saw that I need to use domino developer to do that. But there is no such function in domino developer.

*** The developer client is called Domino Designer, You do not need Domino Designer to create a database but if you want to make design changes you need Domino Designer. (btw. you mentioned that you already installed Domino Designer above)**

**Notes Domino is a client server solution. databases can be local on your machine or on the server. 
Good luck
Thomas**

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: File - Application - New.

I will suggest you find a book and/or online tutorials on the subject of application development in Notes/Domino.

Answer (score 3):

For an excellent introduction to programming Domino in Java, see Bob Balaban's old book -- which is available now for free on his blog [here](http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush).  Yes, it's old, but it covers the basic concepts very, very well.  (The one critical thing that is missing is the recycle() method, which didn't exist at the time he wrote the book, but is absolutely essential.)